# GitLab says merge conflicts must be resolved but there are no conflicts

Tags: git, gitlab, rebase, merge-conflict-resolution, fast-forward

I have a `feature/new-feature` branch that I'm trying to fast-forward merge into `qc` branch. I've been doing this all this time without issues, when all of a sudden today, Gitlab does not allow me to merge due to "Merge blocked: merge conflicts must be resolved.".

I have tried multiple solutions:

1.
Checked out local `git checkout qc`, and `git pull origin qc` (it was up to date). Then rebased my local branch `git rebase -i qc` and forced pushed to origin `git push -f origin feature/new-feature`.

2.
Deleted local `git branch -D qc`, then checked out origin `git checkout qc` and did the rest from step 1.

3.
Unprotected and deleted origin `qc`. Then pushed local `qc` to origin and did the rest from step 1.

4.
Did what GitLab suggested, which is to "resolve locally". Once I merged locally, e.g. on qc `git merge --no-ff 'feature/new-feature'`, and then opened another MR there was still the same merge issue.

5.
Deleted my local repo, and re-cloned again.

Comment: Looks like you have deleted or moved a file locally, that is modified remotely. You should delete it again or apply the remote changes to a new location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was related to deleted files/folders as suggested by someone in the comments. I could not figure out what are these untracked files, so I ended up [git cleaning](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean) the working tree like so:

```
> git checkout qc
> git clean -fd
> git push origin qc
```